# how to compile c++ code to display in a web page (like in PHP)

Tags: c++, compilation, interpreter

I want to compile some C++ code to display in a HTML web page, similar to what is done in PHP.

I also want the option to dynamically interpret C++ Code at runtime just like in PHP.

How do I accomplish the above?

Comment: Point 1: look up [cgi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) (centuries ago, before php came along, we used cgi's that were mostly written in (interpreted) perl, or (compiled) C)).  If you want to make them in C++, [cgicc](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/) will help you.  Point 2: don't know a solution for that, I highly doubt it even exists.

Comment: @fvu could you put your comment as an answer? because its the closest I found to my problem's answer? Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For point 1:

Look up [cgi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) (centuries ago, before php came along, we used cgi's that were mostly written in (interpreted) perl, or (compiled) C)). If you want to make them in C++, [the GNU cgicc library](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/) will help you.

For point 2:

I don't know a solution for that, I highly doubt it even exists.

Answer (score 0):

Heres one solution,

Step 1)
Develop a C++ based web app using a C++ framework such as [C++CMS](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/main), (there may be others I don't know about), Call whatever C++ code you'd like.

Step 2) Load the above C++ web app in a separate iframe and have it interact with the Main Html web app.